# Using Google map objects within a web worker?

Tags: multithreading, google-maps, web-applications, google-maps-api-3, web-worker

The situation:
Too much stuff is running in the main thread of a page making a google map with overlays representing ZIP territories coming from US census data and stuff the client has asked for grouping territories into discreet groups. While there is no major issue on desktops, mobile devices (iPad) decide that the thread is taking too long (max of 6 seconds after data returns) and therefore must have crashed.

Solution: Offload the looping function to gather the points for the shape from each row to a web worker that can work as fast or slow as resources allow on a mobile device. (Three for loops, 1st to select row, 2nd to select column, 3rd for each point within the column. Execution time: matter of 3-6 seconds total for over 2000+ rows with numerous points)

The catch: In order for this to be properly efficient, the points must be made into a shape (polygon) within the web worker. HOWEVER since it is a google.maps.polygon object made up of google.maps.latlng objects it [the web worker] needs to have some knowledge of what those items are within the web worker. Web workers require you to not use window or the DOM so it must import the script and the intent was to pass back just the object as a JSON encoded item. The code fails on any reference of google objects even with importScript() due to the fact those items rely on the window element.

Further complications: Google's API is technically proprietary. The web app code that this is for is bound by NDA so pointed questions could be asked but not a copy/paste of all code.

The solution/any vague ideas:???

TLDR: Need to access google.maps.latlng object and create new instances of (minimally) within a web worker. Web worker should either return Objects ready to be popped into a google.maps.polygon object or should return a google.maps.polygon object. How do I reference the google maps API if I cannot use the default method of importing scripts due to an issue requiring the window object?

**UPDATE**: Since this writing Ive managed to offload the majority of the grunt work from the main thread to the web worker allowing it to parse through the data asynchronously and assign the data to custom made latlng object.

The catch now is getting the returned values to run the function in the proper context to see if the custom latlng is sufficient for google.maps.polygon to work its magic.

Excerpt from the file that calls the web worker and listens for its response (Coffeescript)

```
@shapeWorker.onmessage= (event)->
    console.log "--------------------TESTING---------------"
    data=JSON.parse(event.data)
    console.log data
    @generateShapes(data.poly,data.center,data.zipNum)
```

For some reason, its trying to evaluate GenerateShapes in the context of the web worker rather than in the context of the class its in.

Comment: You may be able to 'request' information from the main thread using postMessage(). Pass the request along to a function that can return the corresponding JSON string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Comment: What would I be requesting that an importScript() would not be able to provide in this instance?

Comment: Just a shot-in-the-dark here... would the ipad not think it has crashed if you updated part of the DOM every second or so ??

Comment: Tried breaking the data up into chunks like that. still got to basically the end and decides the thread "hung" despite being one line away (not actually but it finish drawing polygons and then crashes). Issue occurs with the newest Ipad but not the previous iteration of Ipad.

Comment: Do you need to calculate & initialize all 2000+ points at one go? Why don't you use webstorage and limit the scope and then do your loops?

Comment: The ability to draw based on the shape of the zip codes layout requires all the points. Web storage has limits far below whats needed for the scope of the app...and even smaller on iDevices. I'll update the main question with whats changed.

Comment: It might not be the main issue, but you don't need to instantiate points as google.maps.LatLng object. It is also acceptable to pass in a LatLngLiteral in the form {x:50.5, y:25.5}, which is easily serializable. You have to cast lat and lng as floats beforehand.  May I ask what is your grouping condition?

Comment: I needed the data to be completely prepped for insertion into a polygon object, complete with label, color and the center of the polygon. The issue was doing all of this within the worker so that the dump of data could be put into a polygon without additional overhead. Any additional loops [to parse through points] on the main thread side would cause a loss of any efficiency gained by pushing it to an asynchronous web worker. Otherwise I was going out to a web worker and prepping data that still needed evaluation and coming back and tying up the main thread with blocking zip code shape logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again it was a complication of too many things going on at once. The scope was restricted due to the usage of -> rather than => which expands the scope to allow the parent class functions.

Apparently the issue resided with the version of iOS this web app needed to run on and a bug with the storage being set arbitrarily low (a tenth of its previous size). With some shrinking of the data and a fix to the iOS version in question I was able to get it running without the usage of web workers. One day I may be able to come back to it with web workers to increase efficiency.